# Background-color for a div around all content inside

Tags: html, css, height, css-shapes

I'm working on a 'arrow'-div. It currently looks like this:

[image]

the div contains two other divs(two lines). And I want that the background is nearly wrapped around the lines. But the height of the yellow-background is a lot smaller than the height of the lines. I already tried 'height: auto'. I hope someone could help me out.

```css
#lineAll {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: auto;
}

#line1 {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  width: 40px;
}

#line2 {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lineAll">
  <div id="line1"></div>
  <div id="line2"></div>
</div>
```

edit:

The width is also not the way I want it. It's currently 100%-width of the screen.

Comment: The height is already automatically as big as the content. But because of the rotation your divs are overlaying - but the calculated height of the parent div still is the same.  So you can't get the height automatically. Try adding a fixed height.

Comment: try having a div which wraps the whole content inside with like a padding of 15px and add the `background-color` to that.

Comment: With a fixed height, the bottom-part gets bigger but not the top-part. A fixed with does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style="background-color : yellow; padding: 15px 0px; width: 40px;">
    <div id="lineAll">
       <div id="line1"></div>
       <div id="line2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
#lineAll {
   background-color: yellow;
   height: auto;
}

#line1 {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  width: 40px;
}

#line2 {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with one element and `:after` pseudo-element. Just create smaller pseudo-element that has `border-top` and `border-right` and then rotate it for `45deg`.

```css
.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.element:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

To create other button just rotate for `-135deg` and set `right: 0px`

```css
.element {
  width: 50px;
  height: 60px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}
.element:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.element.right:after {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
<div class="element right"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try drawing a triangle shape with `css` since it gives the same result you want to achieve

```css
.triangle {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 108px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 108px solid transparent;
    border-left: 108px solid #4abdac;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="triangle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I only want the two lines, it's some kind of triangle but your example is not exactly what i want.

Comment: Question answered. I probably didn't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#lineAll {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/j4aza1om/

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
overflow: hidden;
display: inline-block;
```

```css
#lineAll {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

#line1 {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(35deg);
  width: 40px;
}

#line2 {
  height: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  transform: rotate(-35deg);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="lineAll">
  <div id="line1"></div>
  <div id="line2"></div>
</div>
```